# Beginning Java (Help)

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a self-study AP Java course and I just need some quick help. I have this issue with the paintComponent. I am always receiving messages to override it and create other things for it. This is my code for that class:

```
package pkghello;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 *
 * @author ap
 */
public class RectangleComponent extends JComponent {


    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) //It only highlights "paintComponent"
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle (5,10,20,30);
        g2.draw(box);
        box.translate(90, 90);
        box.setSize(150,150);
        g2.draw(box);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 2):

Two things.  It probably wants you to add the `@Override` annotation and, unless you really need it to be otherwise, `paintComponent` should remain `protected`

For example.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g)
```

Comment: Although there isn't really a question asked here, this is probably the answer :) +1

Comment: @JoshM It's at least a recommendation :P